# Symfony Workflow initial_place parameter not working

Tags: symfony, workflow

workflow.yaml:

```
framework:
workflows:
    test_workflow:
        type: 'workflow'
        marking_store:
            type: 'single_state'
            arguments:
                - 'currentPlace'
        supports:
            - App\Entity\Call
        initial_place: draft
        places:
            - draft
            - ok
            - notok
        transitions:
            go:
                from: draft
                to:   ok
            reject:
                from: draft
                to:   notok
```

My Controller:

```
public function twf(Registry $workflows){

    $c = new Call();
    $workflow = $workflows->get($c);
    return $this->render('page/twf.html.twig',[ 
        'cp' => $c->getCurrentPlace()
    ]);
}
```

It just shows nothing , but when applying the Go transition , it displays the 'ok' which is expected , I wonder why it's not taking the configured initial_place when the Call object is first initiated !

Any hints ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it only sets the state to the initial after something triggers it. Requesting the workflow object is not enough.

Try calling `getMarking`, it should be set after that... you can see the set part here: https://github.com/symfony/workflow/blob/master/Workflow.php#L63

Comment: Thanks for your comment, it's very helpful !! , it worked even though I find it to be a little bit strange from the Workflow Component to not set the initialPlace automatically , but anyway , big big thanks!! ^_^

Comment: It is strange indeed. I think it warrants an RFC in symfony issues. Setting the initial state on construct would be better, more expectable behaviour.

Comment: that's it absolutely